# How to change mysql open_files_limit value?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.0.67. How do I change the value of `open_files_limit`? I have already put the `open_files_limit` variable in `my.ini` file, in `[mysqld]` sector and `[mysqld_safe]` sector, but it doesn't change anything. I also try using `open-files-limit` variable, but it still not change. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: To increase the hard file limit on Linux use `ulimit -Hn new_number`, q.v. [this article](https://linuxdevops.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/why-raising-the-mysql-open_files_limit-may-not-work-and-how-to-fix-it/).  On Windows, you may not be able to change the hard limit, q.v. [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.mysql/fU8XYkvUxPA).

Comment: I'm running MySQL in Windows. If the `open_files_limit` value 2048, would it have any effect to huge data?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64564698/9731538

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't use this engine anymore.